# google maps v3: referers ignored

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps v3 and therefor have generated an api key in google's "apis conosole". I am loading the map with the key as parameter. As I can see the statistics in the api-project account, I am quite sure this works smooth.

Now I want to limit the domains which should be able to use a specific key, so I added an entry in "Referers" in the following way: "www.domain.com". I have assumed that if I load the map from a differnt domain (i.e. www.domain.org) I would receive an error, which does not happen. The map is loaded without any warnings (even not in chrome's console). In the apis console these "wrong" referers are even listed.

Additional info: all pages are using a single google app engine account and multiple google apps domains.

Any ideas what my mistake might be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enter full url or wildcards.

```
http://www.domain.com/*
```

or

```
*.domain.com/*
```

Probably if you dont have at least one value entry - it's ignored (to stop you completely shooting yourself in the foot)

Comment: thanks for the reply... but it is still ignored. I can use the key from any other domain.

Comment: Are you perhaps hardcoding a specific version of the API - and choosing a old version?

Comment: this is my api-call (extracted directly from Chrome):

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&key=<my_key>&language=de&libraries=places,geometry&callback=google.loader.callbacks.maps